# Как называется класс списка содержащий разреженный массив?

Tags: массивы, list, терминология

Есть некоторый список/массив в который сущности добавляют некоторые элементы и получают токен (позицию в массиве). На время жизни сущностей и элементов, их положение в массиве не меняется (т.о. токен все время указывает на элемент добавленный сущностью. При уничтожении сущности (или если сущность решает удалить элемент), элемент в массиве зануляется и отмечается свободным, а сущность "забывает" токен. Таким образом, есть некоторый разреженный пул элементов, гарантирующий доступ к элементам по токенам (в простейшем случае - токен = индекс).

Естественно, получается, что число элементов <> размеру массива в котором они хранятся, и естественно, итератор знает как пропускать "пустые" элементы. Вопрос об экономии ресурсов также не стоит - элементов не сильно много и O(n^2) на таких порядках не сильно отличается от O(n), но в будущем, конечно, внутреннюю реализацию можно будет изменить. Сейчас вопрос о самом простом случае - списке/массиве. Также, токены гораздо проще сериализуются/десериализуются.

Т.к. этот подход используется в программе несколько раз, хочу сделать один общий дженерик класс, и далее подставлять в него нужные типы элементов.

Вопрос - как правильно называется такой "список", в котором элементы не меняют своих положений?

Comment: Ну я знаю только sparse matrix на эту тему, но это не совсем то )

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо за подсказку. Словарь это не совсем то, т.к. в моем случае ключа нету (и сделать его затруднительно, т.к. добавляют элементы разнородные сущности и иногда больше 1). Делать ключ=значению не очень получится, т.к. важна сериализация/десериализация (забыл упомянуть). Также, хотелось бы пока все же сделать реализацию на простом списке/массиве, т.к. элементов мало и вычисления хэшей и проверки коллизий заметно дольше по времени, чем просто индекс.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, спасибо за идеи. Генерация, хранение и раздача ключей выглядит избыточно, если их можно заменить индексом. В любом случае, ***вопрос о том как обычно называется описанная структура, а не как её заменить на словарь*** )